# How to calculate a full set of dependencies using Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I need to create a solution for a transaction coming into a system, this transaction needs to validate and retrieve information, after needs to send the info to a processor. The inputs for the transaction are as below:

```
[
    {
        "Inputs": [
            {
                "Input": "A B C"
            },
            {
                "Input": "B C E "
            },
            {
                "Input": "C G"
            },
            {
                "Input": "D A F"
            },
            {
                "Input": "E F"
            },
            {
                "Input": "F H "
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

In the message, the first token is the name of an item (e.g. A). The remaining tokens are the names of things that this first item depends on (e.g. B C).

The program should then calculate the full set of dependencies to the group of items, For example, looking at A above, we see it directly depends on B and C. B in turn relies on C and E, C relies on G and E has no dependencies. This means that A ultimately relies on B, C, E, and G. The full set of dependencies and the output of my code should be as below:

```
A B C E F G H    
B C E F G H    
C G    
D A B C E F G H    
E F H    
F H
```

this is what I have so far:

```
public class Dependency
{
    public string Input { get; set; }
}
public class Wrapper
{
    public List<Dependency> Inputs { get; set; }
}

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:inputs.json"))
{              
    string json = sr.ReadToEnd();

    List<Wrapper> f = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Wrapper>>(json);

    List<Dependency> dep = new List<Dependency>();

    var test = f.FirstOrDefault();
    //saving inputs to list
    foreach (var t in test.Inputs)
    {
        dep.Add(t);
    }
    var startPoint = new List<string>();
    // cleaning up whitespaces
    foreach (var a in test.Inputs)
    {
        var test1 = a.Input.Trim();
        startPoint.Add(test1);
    }

    var dict = startPoint.ToDictionary(a => a, b => b);
}
```

I am using a dictionary to achieve the dependency for the letters but I am not sure how to set the key and values.

this is the add to watch from my code running.

[image]

The result of of this code should be as below:

```
A B C E F G H    
B C E F G H    
C G    
D A B C E F G H    
E F H    
F H
```

Comment: I'm utterly unclear how you'd get `A B C E F G H` from that. There is no `G H` or `G`/`H` separately in the input. In general, the relation between your input and output is mysterious. If this is a simplified version of your problem, consider un-simplifying it.

Comment: The correlation between your inputs and your outputs does not make sense to me. The JSON doesn't seem to be relevant here. Can you please just provide the input as plain old C# and then describe how you expect the output to be computed?

Comment: I need to calculate the full set of dependencies to the group of items, For example, looking at A, we see it directly depends on B and C. B in turn relies on C and E, C relies on G and E has no dependencies. This means that A ultimately relies on B, C, E, and G. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: `This means that A ultimately relies on B, C, E, and G.` `A B C E F G H` I am struggling to reconcile those two contradictory statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a fairly neat LINQ-based solution. I've taken the liberty of starting with `inputs` as an array of strings.

```
string[] inputs = new[]
{
    "A B C",
    "B C E ",
    "C G",
    "D A F",
    "E F",
    "F H ",
};
```

First remove the spaces - they just get in the way:

```
inputs =
    inputs
        .Select(x => x.Replace(" ", ""))
        .ToArray();
```

Make a lookup to map the first character to each of the subsequent characters.

```
ILookup<char, char> paths =
    inputs
        .SelectMany(x => x.Skip(1).Select(y => new { x0 = x[0], x1 = y }))
        .ToLookup(x => x.x0, x => x.x1);
```

Next recurse over the lookup to build the list of dependencies.

```
IEnumerable<char> expand(char key)
    => paths[key]
        .SelectMany(x => expand(x))
        .OrderBy(x => x)
        .StartWith(key)
        .Distinct();
```

The `OrderBy` is import to ensure the output order is as specified in the question. The `Distinct` is required because there are multiple paths to some of the dependencies.

Finally put it all together:

```
IEnumerable<string> result =
    inputs
        .Select(x => expand(x[0]))
        .Select(x => String.Join(" ", x));
```

The `result` is:

```
A B C E F G H 
B C E F G H 
C G 
D A B C E F G H 
E F H 
F H
```

---

To replace my hard-coded array at the start of my answer you just just use this code:

```
var json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:inputs.json");
List<Wrapper> f = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Wrapper>>(json);
string[] inputs = f.SelectMany(x => x.Inputs, (x, y) => y.Input).ToArray();
```

Comment: @aline - Sorry, but I didn't change the input. Instead of getting the array of strings from JSON I just hard-coded it in C#. It's just so that I didn't need all the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After understand your problem, which I think it is a logical exercise. I reached in a correct output.

You will need a recursive method to populate all the chain of dependencies from a letter.

I made some changes in your code to fit my solutio, basicaly i'm using a dicntionary whitch  the values are List.

Recursive Method:

```
    public List<string> GetDependenciesFrom (Dictionary<string, List<string>> rules, string key)
    {
        // it contains itself 
        List<string> result = new List<string> { key };

        if (rules.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            foreach (var val in rules[key])
            {
                if (!result.Contains(val))
                {
                    result.Add(val);
                    foreach (string newval in GetDependenciesFrom(rules, val))
                    {
                        if (!result.Contains(newval))
                        {
                            result.Add(newval);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

And here is you code with some changes:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\temp\inputs.json"))
{
    string json = sr.ReadToEnd();

    Wrapper f = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Wrapper>>(json).FirstOrDefault();

    // saving inputs to list
    if (f != null)
    {
        List<Dependency> dep = new List<Dependency>();
        foreach (Dependency t in f.Inputs)
        {
            dep.Add(t);
        }

        Dictionary<string, List<string>> startPoint = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        foreach (var a in f.Inputs)
        {
            string[] list = a.Input.Trim().Split(' ');
            startPoint.Add(list.First(), list.ToList());
        }

        Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        foreach (var k in startPoint)
        {
            dict.Add(k.Key, GetDependenciesFrom(startPoint, k.Key));
        }


        // Just to print results
        foreach (var key in dict)
        {
            Console.Write(key.Key + ": ");
            foreach (var val in key.Value)
            {
                Console.Write(val + " ");
            }

            Console.Write("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

```
A: A B C G E F H
B: B C G E F H
C: C G
D: D A B C G E F H
E: E F H
F: F H
```

Comment: @aline I know that maybe you have the answer, but ... I posted another solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{
    var data = JArray.Parse(@"
    [{
        'Inputs': [ 
            {'Input': 'A B C'},
            {'Input': 'B C E '},
            {'Input': 'C G'},
            {'Input': 'D A F'},
            {'Input': 'E F'},
            {'Input': 'F H'}
        ]
    }]
    ");
    var values = data.SelectTokens("..Input").Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
    var dict = values.ToDictionary(s => s[0], v => v.Substring(2).Where(Char.IsLetter).ToArray());

    IEnumerable<char> Dependencies(char input)
    {
        yield return input;
        if(dict.TryGetValue(input, out char[] childDepends))
        {
            foreach(char result in childDepends.SelectMany(Dependencies))
            {
                yield return result;
            }
        }
    }

    foreach(char s in values.Select(x => x[0]))
    {
        Console.Write(s);Console.Write(" ");
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", dict[s].SelectMany(Dependencies).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x)));
    }
}
```

Output

```
A B C E F G H
B C E F G H
C G
D A B C E F G H
E F H
F H
```

Comment: @aline I don't believe I changed the inputs from the original post. Are you saying they're different?

If this solution was correct, please mark as the answer, or at least up-vote.